# After loading R script, it returns lots of dot

Tags: r

I have been working on an R script for the last several weeks. When I opened this R script this morning, I found nothing but a list of dots showed in the attached figure. I tried both RStudio and R i386, and returned the same result. I also asked my colleague to open it, but he also failed even open it in the text file. The .Rhistory can not be well opened either. Could someone help me out? You can find the R script in the shared link below. Many thanks.

[image]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w3wbArOXjRoOXJlrrDvHxFDjwqNobjcy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: After opening it with HexEditor, I found it only contains `00` bytes. You lost your script, I'm afraid.

Comment: I would imagine that the script is lost. You might be lucky that a previous version can be regained through google drives [file versioning](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2409045?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en#:~:text=View%20past%20activity,the%20left%20click%20My%20Drive.&text=To%20see%20recent%20changes%2C%20click,click%20the%20file%20or%20folder.). Otherwise you'll likely have to bite the apple and rebuild it from scratch. In addition this seems to be a question more suited for [superuser](https://superuser.com/) as it is not specifically about programming.

Comment: The size of the R script is 66 kb in my laptop, I really do not understand what happened to this script when I save it last Friday in RStudio. Never have this kind of problem before. I remind me to save different versions. Thanks for your kind help, I will start everything again if I can not recover it.

Comment: I checked too, your file is corrupted probably. Try opening it with Notepad++ and you'll see lot of NULL

Comment: Hi Kay, thanks for your kind check. I think I have lost them and need to rebuild it. It motivates me to go for Git.